# undefined method `%' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror, fixnum

I am getting "NoMethodError: undefined method `%' for nil:NilClass" for the following code block:

```
class Timer
    attr_accessor :seconds

    def initialize
        @seconds = 0
    end

    def time_string

        if seconds < 10
            return "00:00:0" + seconds.to_s
        elsif seconds < 60
            return "00:00:" + seconds.to_s
        elsif seconds < 540
            minutes = seconds / 60
            seconds %= 60
            #seconds = seconds - (minutes * 60)
            return "00:0" + minutes.to_s + ":0" + seconds.to_s
        end
    end

    def timer
        @timer          
    end
end
```

I know that 'seconds' is a Fixnum because I get NoMethod: Fixnum error when I try to #puts seconds without a #to_s. Also, the "/" operation on 'seconds' in the preceding line works fine. So why am I getting a NoMethod:nilclass error message?

Why am I even getting an error message? Shouldn't "%" work everywhere "/" does?

The following code works:

```
        if seconds < 10
            return "00:00:0" + seconds.to_s
        elsif seconds < 60
            return "00:00:" + seconds.to_s
        elsif seconds < 540
            minutes = @seconds / 60
            seconds = @seconds % 60
            return "00:0" + minutes.to_s + ":0" + seconds.to_s
        end
```

It has something to do with instance variables, and my not understanding instance variables. would love to know how the nil got in there.

Comment: The above should works fine, see: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/dbaa9

Comment: Updated to show the whole class, not just the method. That commented out line generates the same error. It's like all the operators suddenly just stop working.

Comment: The code works, see here: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/5e554. Your issue is somewhere else methinks.

Comment: I saw that, and substituted the rubyfiddle code for my own. got the same result. No idea where else the issue could be, this is a tutorial so there's literally just this and the rake file.

Comment: How are you calling this? It is from a rails controller?

Comment: That error message should cite a specific line. The error indicates you are attempting to apply the operator `%` to a `nil` object, which clearly isn't the case here since otherwise `seconds / 60` would fail. So the error message must be applicable to some other part of the code you're not showing perhaps. You say the code is "just this and the rake file". What rake file? There can be a lot of code in a rake file.

Comment: Try `self.seconds %= 60`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interaction between methods called on `self`, local variables, and Ruby's lack of syntactic distinction between those things.

If you change the line to this:

```
         self.seconds %= 60
```

Then it works fine.

The problem is that when Ruby sees an assignment to an unqualified name, it creates a local variable with that name rather than looking for an accessor.

Here's a simple demonstration:

```
irb(main):001:0> def foo=(n)
irb(main):002:1>  puts "Calling foo!"
irb(main):003:1>  @foo=n
irb(main):004:1> end    #=> nil
irb(main):005:0> foo=1    #=> 1
irb(main):006:0> @foo    #=> nil
irb(main):007:0> self.foo=2
Calling foo!
=> 2
irb(main):008:0> @foo    #=> 2
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a concept I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around.

Comment: It's pretty simple.  When Ruby sees a qualified assignment like `foo.bar = baz`, it looks for an accessor method `bar=` on the object referenced by `foo`.  But when it sees an unqualified assignment like `bar=baz`, it doesn't look for any accessor methods, because no object is present.  It just creates a local variable.  The fact that an unqualified explicit *method call* will be sent to `self` doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100%  sure about this, but I believe this is a precedence issue.

Since operators always have precedence over methods, the `%= 2` is being evaluated before the `seconds` getter method is being evaluated. This is what would be causing the `NoMethodError`, I believe.

This would also explain why using `@seconds` works, since you're referencing the instance variable directly and not using the getter method that `attr_accessor` creates behind the scenes.

As a side note, I think it makes more sense to use the instance variable in this case from a class design perspective.

**Edit**: What I said above can't be correct, because methods such as this work:

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :length

  def midpoint
    length / 2
  end
end
```

I think it's much more simple that that, actually. I assume that `%=` works the same other assignment operators like `+=` in that writing `seconds %= 60` is the same as writing `seconds = seconds % 60`.

What is likely happening then is that since you're assigning something to `seconds`, ruby interprets that as a new local variable called `seconds`. When the `%=` is "expanded" into `seconds = seconds % 60`, the `seconds` on the right-hand side is interpreted as the same local variable, which is currently `nil`. Hence, the `NoMethodError`.

Comment: The edit is the correct answer.  If you replace `seconds` with either `self.seconds` (explicitly calling the accessors) or `@seconds` (bypassing the accessors and hitting the instance variable directly) the code works as intended.